# Use all 100% power of CPU with C#

Tags: c#, performance, cryptography, cpu

i'm trying to rewrite [Vanitygen](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen) in C#. This is my code for now

```
 private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            KeyPair kp = KeyPair.Create(ExtraEntropy.GetEntropy()); //Generate private key
            string wifprivatekey = new KeyPair(kp.PrivateKeyBytes).PrivateKeyBase58; //Create wif private key
            string address = new AddressBase(kp, AddressTypeByte).AddressBase58);// Create base 58 address

                if (address.StartsWith(pattern)) //compare value with input pattern
                {
                    using (var writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\ran242\Desktop\result.txt"))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Pattern: "+pattern);
                        writer.WriteLine("Address: "+address);
                        writer.WriteLine("Privatekey: "+wifprivatekey);
                    }
                }  
    }
```

I test it to run mutiple time using `Parallel.For`. The code run really slow for now, so i intend to improve the performance. When run on parallel, it can only check 1000 address for like 3 seconds & it didn't even use all CPU power

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 1000, i =>
        {
           KeyPair kp = KeyPair.Create(ExtraEntropy.GetEntropy()); //Generate private key
        string wifprivatekey = new KeyPair(kp.PrivateKeyBytes).PrivateKeyBase58; //Create wif private key
        string address = new AddressBase(kp, AddressTypeByte).AddressBase58);// Create base 58 address

            if (address.StartsWith(pattern)) //compare value with input pattern
            {
                using (var writer = File.AppendText(@"C:\Users\ran242\Desktop\result.txt"))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("Pattern: "+pattern);
                    writer.WriteLine("Address: "+address);
                    writer.WriteLine("Privatekey: "+wifprivatekey);
                }
            }  
        });
```

[image]

Is there any method that i can improve the code & use 100% of my CPU or any CPU whenever i run this code on different computer? thank you

Comment: You're doing **file I/O** - there is your bottleneck.  Throwing threads at it is not going to improve anything

Comment: I just remove  file I/O & run it. It's pretty much the same performance :v

Comment: try to hold result in List and finally dump list result to file

Comment: As MickyD says it, this is not a CPU bound operation but a Disk bound one. If anything throwing more threads at it will add Thread management overhead, making it slower. | As for properly replicating Vanitygen: I doubt that will happen. It is written in C, wich allows all the Micro--optimsiations moderns day programmers do not deal with. .NET is in no way noticeably slwoer in common use cases, but that programm is a high performance BitCoin miner (I think, the description is wierd).

Comment: I also noticed you got WriteLines in there. Writing to the user is **expensive**. If you only do it once per user triggered event, you will not notice. But from a loop, the speed of consoel drawing can easily become **the** bottleneck. Try just minimizing the Console window and see if the performance improoves. I run my fair share of console commands monthly, and if hte processing is short the Console overhead becoems massive.

Comment: @AzarShaikh already try that, too. It freeze the computer longer than than the time i run my original code

Comment: You have several problems here, and its hard to know where to start. but mainly, the Default Task Scheduler its just not going to throw threads at you the way you want. This is why you are neither maxing the CPU or your disk throughput.

Comment: You're also writing to the same file from multiple threads... that's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Christopher ok, i commented out the WriteLines & still nothing changes

Comment: @HuangLee: "It freeze the computer longer than than the time i run my original code" If storing stuff in a list in memory takes longer, then you either exceed the freely adressable space (wich causes the swap file to be used) or something is massively wrong with the code that writes the list to the disk.

Comment: @Sunius isn't vanitygen use the same way when print the result to file? How can i fix this

Comment: you are allocating all over the place and creating excess garbage pressure, you are inefficiently using file writes which should be safely threaded and cached and written in optimal chunks,, TPL is bottle-necking your threads, the list goes on and on.

Comment: @Christopher vanitygen when run only on cpu check about 100k address per seconds (about 20kb for 3 line of pattern, private key & address), that's like 2gb of data. I don't think they write data to disk & compare it, that definitely make the hardrive overheat & crash the computer

Comment: @HuangLee i think Christopher has given you the best answer you can hope for, Stackoverflow is not a place to optimise your code, and you have too many gaps in your knowledge to provide you a satisfying answer

Comment: This questions is too broad and lacks sufficient knowledge and usefulness to benefit the OP or any future user, as such it should be closed

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do is close to [realtime progtramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing). That is not something you can just do or learn on a whim.

Realtime Proramming is a highly specialized area of programming, with specialized *Operating Systems*. One for wich C# and .NET are pretty unsuited to begin with. A JiT compiled, Garbage Collected runtime is not the right environment for Realtime Programming. That is **why** the original programm was written in C.

As best as I can tell, you are trying to programm way above your skill level. You need to learn Multitasking first before you even got a shoot at it. Then you need to know if this problem is even [Pleasingly Paralelizeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleasingly_parallel) or at when it suffers [Paralell Slowdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Race_conditions,_mutual_exclusion,_synchronization,_and_parallel_slowdown). On your comptuer, mind you. Stuff like the Swapfile can easily get in the way of this kind of performance.

Comment: ok, before i close this discussion. Can you have any knowledge about this? my school server have System Configuration like this:
General purpose CPU nodes:
236 nodes (471.24 TFLOPS) CPU : Intel Xeon Gold 6126 (Skylake / 2.6 GHz 12 cores) 2 CPUs
Memory : 192GB. If i run this code on it wouldn't it run any faster?

Comment: @HuangLee: Way to much uncertainty to give you a answer. Indeed the best I can do is give you the speed rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @HuangLee i would think very seriously about your next comments, what you are doing if you could, would probably get you kicked out of school

Comment: @TheGeneral lol, no. you could send request to use school system in a day or two. as long as it not hacking or stealing things